# cursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: index 0 is requested with size 0

Tags: android

i am trying to search a specific element from database.
my database has three coloumns name, number and message. here is my function

```
   public void getmessage() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String msg;
String number = "1112";
String [] columns = new String[]{row_name,row_contactno,row_message};
String whereClause = row_contactno + " = ?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[]{number};
Cursor v = ourdatabase.query(database_table, columns, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null);

    if(v != null)
    {
    v.moveToFirst(); 
    int id = v.getColumnIndex(row_message);
    msg = v.getString(id);
        Toast.makeText(ourcontext, msg.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    ourdatabase.close();
    }
```

but when i run this, i am getting CURSORINDEXOUTOFBOUNDS exception : index 0 is requested with size 0

can anyone help me in finding the error in my code...!!

Answer (score 3):

you need to move this

```
v.moveToFirst();
```

into your `if statement` so that if the cursor has nothing in it, it will be false and not do anything in the if.

```
if(v != null && v.moveToFirst())
```

also dont forget to close the cursor after the if statement `v.close()`

Comment: for FSM sake! there is no need to check if `v` is `null` ... `SQLiteDatabase.query` **will never** return `null` ...

Answer (score -1):

Your query is not returning any row as result in cursor. So cursor `count` is `0` , so before iterating the cursor check cursor `count` i.e.

```
if(v != null &&v.getCount()!=0)
 {
    v.moveToFirst(); 

   // do your work.
 }
```

Comment: why `getCount()` + `moveToFirst()` ? `moveToFirst()` is enough ... you need to check **if cursor is not empty**, **not how many rows** are in  the cursor! second: there is no need to check if `v` is `null` ... SQLiteDatabase.query will never return null